# I would love it versus I would love

Tags: grammar, rules

What is correct?

> "I would love if you could do that"

versus

> "I would love **it** if you could do that"

Is there a general rule I can follow in cases like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I would love it if you could do that"

This is normal and idiomatic conversational English. It can be compared with "I would love life if you could do that".  The use of "it" is impersonal, as in "It is raining."

> "I would love if you could do that"

Again this is heard in conversation but it is more difficult to justify in terms of grammar. It is not obvious how the expression "if you could do that" could be a valid direct object of the verb "love".

Another possibility:

> "I would love you to do that"

In grammatical terms this could be considered to be a shortened form of the less common phrase

> "I would love for you to do that."

In this latter version it can be seen that "for you to do that" can be used in place of a noun. Example: "For John to have done that showed a great deal of courage."

Comment: Why would “if you could do that” not be valid as a direct object of _love_? _Love_ can take subordinate clauses as its object—both complement clauses and relative adverbial clauses are possible, so why not conditional clauses?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It's a fair point. Maybe I'm really objecting for a different reason. I'll give it some thought.